# How to formatting date to this '2015-02-03T05:04:01+0000' in python

Tags: python, datetime

please, help to formatting any file creation date to such format:

```
'2015-02-03T05:04:01+0000'
```

I have already tried many formats, but its not working. Please help to solve this issue.

So, the basic script to get file creation date is:

```
import os.path, time
import datetime

file = r'path to file'
print "created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve in more detail? What do you have, that you want to format, a datetime object? Can you show a code example that you tried and explain how it does not give you what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse text to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object, use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-02-03T05:04:01+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1)
```

You can see the format I used (`'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000'`) you can see the full details on how the format works on the link I provided, also keep in mind that you can use normal chars (like the `T` or `+0000`) to match the exact format you had.

Answer (score 0):

Here Duan is right. But for the "+0000" you can use "%z".

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.today(),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

Other formatting char you can see here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html